Add rows to table produced with filter function based on additional argument
This is an extension to a question I previously asked and had answered Populate rows on different sheet based on cell value on other sheet
I have a master spreadsheet which contains all subjects e.g.

If value in column D is 'TRUE' I wish to populate row on second sheet with the first three columns (cells in red are copied through, cells in black manually entered.

The solution given in the original question works perfectly, i.e. =FILTER(A2:C4,D2:D4=TRUE)
I would now like to enter additional rows to the second sheet, based on the value in column F. If column F is False, I would like an additional row with the first three columns repeated.

This would continue to repeat if 'FALSE' was entered again in column F.
Ideally this would be automated (e.g. by value in column F or similar), but if this is not possible, is there a way to achieve this manually whilst keeping the original FILTER function working?

Look into VSTACK.

One problem is that to achieve this dynamically (meaning that a row will insert when you enter FALSE in column F), your original array result will also have to depend on column F. But that means that you could find that your entries in column F don't align with the names they should. Example: in your second screenshot above, imagine entering FALSE in F3. Then "alec jones" would go down to row 5 (being part of the red array result), but the TRUE entry in F4 would now be lined up with the (new) third "aaron smith" row. This is potentially very risky.

To avoid your new inputs (column F) modifying your first array result, I would recommend using an intermediate sheet. So:

Sheet1: original data
Sheet2: column headers, plus =FILTER(A2:C4,D2:D4=TRUE) in A2 (as above)
Sheet3: new sheet for 'dynamic' entry with rows adding automatically (as below)

In Sheet3, add column headers as above in row A. Additionally, add an 'Offset' column (column G) and a single cell in (say) J1 which is the total row count of your first result. One simple method:

J1: =COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A) - 1 (-1 to exclude headers)

Additionally, set G2 (i.e. the first 'Offset' cell) to 1.
Now configure row 3 as follows (we use row 3 so you can copy 'up' to row 2, except for the 'Offset' column, as well as down to the maximum plausible extent of your range):

A3: =IF($G3 = "", "", OFFSET(Sheet2!A$1, $G3, 0))
B3: =IF($G3 = "", "", OFFSET(Sheet2!B$1, $G3, 0))
C3: =IF($G3 = "", "", OFFSET(Sheet2!C$1, $G3, 0))

(You can copy A3 across to B3 and C3, because of the relative row references.)

D3-F3: Manual entry
G3: =IF(G2="", "", IF(AND(G2=$J$1, OR(F2 = "", F2)), "", G2 + (IF(F2 = "", 1, IF(F2, 1, 0)))))

Now, as stated, copy row 3 down as far as needed, and A3:C3 up to A2:C2 (but leave G2 hard-coded to 1).
You should find that by entering TRUE or FALSE in column F, the range resizes as you require.
You must still work downwards, otherwise any previously entered values in columns D and E (below your current working cell) will become misaligned.
Here is an illustration of Sheet3 to help:

Here is an animated GIF to illustrate:

And here is a link to a (read-only) Google Sheet which illustrates the behaviour.
You might of course need to adapt this for your needs by adding error handling etc.

You will need an additional formula like this:
=LET(
    source,Sheet2!A2#,header,Sheet2!A1:F1,
    data, HSTACK(source,OFFSET(source,0,COLUMNS(source),,3)),
    result, DROP(
                REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(x,r,IF(INDEX(data,r,6) = FALSE,
                        VSTACK(x,CHOOSEROWS(data,r),MAP(CHOOSEROWS(data,r),SEQUENCE(,6),LAMBDA(c,i,CHOOSE(i,c,c,c,INDEX(data,r,4)+1,"","")))),
                        VSTACK(x,CHOOSEROWS(data,r))))),
            1),
    VSTACK(header,result)
    )

It checks per row from Sheet2 if 6th column (= column F) is FALSE, if so two rows are created, with the second row adjusting the data in the last columns (-> CHOOSE-part).
If you want to you could put the formula on Sheet 2 as well - like in the screenshot

